# How to pass a generic decodable data using a delegate

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, delegates, decodable

I have managed to create an `APIClient` and router for my app and here is my code

my result

```
enum Result<T> {
    case success(data: T)
    case failure(error: Error) }
```

Here is my server request

```
func request<T: Decodable>(router: APIRouter, completion: @escaping (Result<T>) -> ()) {
```

And the completion handler

```
completion(Result<T>.failure(error: ErrorResult.defaultError))
completion(Result.success(data: result))
```

And here is my `viewModel` where i am getting the result

```
switch result {
        case .success(let successData):
            print("successData \(successData)")
            self.viewModelDelegate?.didFinishFetchingData(successData)

        case .failure(let errorData):
            print("errorData \(errorData.localizedDescription)")
            self.viewModelDelegate?.didFinishFetchingDataWithFailure?(errorData.localizedDescription)
        }
```

Now what i need is i want to pass the result as decodable to my viewcontroller using delegate

```
@objc public protocol ViewModelDelegate {
func didStartFetchingData()
func didFinishFetchingData(_ result:Decodable)
@objc optional func didFinishFetchingDataWithFailure(_ message:String)
}
```

This is what I did but it is getting error

**All I need is I want to pass the success data (decodable data) to my view controller from view model using custom delegate**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do generic with this, check out the below example

```
 func didFinishFetchingData<T: Decodable>(_ result: T)

// example models 
struct Foo: Decodable {

}
struct Boo: Decodable {

}
didFinishFetchingData(Foo())
didFinishFetchingData(Boo())
```

To make it optional as you need , simply add `?` in `T` .

```
func didFinishFetchingData<T: Decodable>(_ result: T?)
```

**Note** : You can't pass plain `nil` into the parameter but you can pass a nullable type of `T` check the code below .

```
let model = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Foo.self, from: Data()) // model is type of Foo? 
didFinishFetchingData(model) // works fine
```

Comment: can i make result optional ?

Comment: `func didFinishFetchingData<T: Decodable>(_ result: T?)`

Comment: When i tried to pass nil value it showing "Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred"

Comment: @MidhunNarayan check update guess that should be it

Comment: `func didFinishFetchingData<T: Decodable>(_ result: T)` how to get result as my model data inside this function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197084/discussion-between-midhun-narayan-and-mohmmad-s).